# Why do raw pointers need the const keyword when references don't?

Tags: rust

Please reference the code below, for the line which has been commented out. It cannot be compiled by the Rust compiler, meaning we need to specify the constness like `*const i32` explicitly for a raw pointer in Rust. But for a reference that is immutable to its pointee, we don't need to specify the constness explicitly like with a raw pointer. So, why does Rust not use a more symmetrical way to express the same meaning for both references and raw pointers, since the reference is actually a pointer under the hood?

```
fn main() {
    let x1: &i32;
    let x2: &mut i32;
    // let p1: *i32;  // This line doesn't compile!!!
    let p1: *const i32;  // we need to specify the constness explicitly.
    let p2: *mut i32;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Early versions of Rust (pre-1.0) used `*T` for `const` raw pointers (with the same syntax as you note does not work today). [RFC 0068](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0068-const-unsafe-pointers.html) renamed `*T` to `*const T`, with justification that it is more error-prone to use `*T` when transcribing type signatures from existing C code:

> The current difference in Rust unsafe pointers types with C pointers types is proving to be too error prone to realistically enable these optimizations at a future date. By renaming Rust's unsafe pointers to closely match their C brethren, the likelihood for erroneously transcribing a signature is diminished.

The RFC also notes (as you do) that this introduces an inconsistency in naming between references and raw pointers:

> Today's unsafe pointers design is consistent with the borrowed pointers types in Rust, using the `mut` qualifier for a mutable pointer, and no qualifier for an "immutable" pointer. Renaming the pointers would be divergence from this consistency, and would also introduce a keyword that is not used elsewhere in the language, `const`.